# Python QT create app. that can interactively receive from and send to a CLI script

Tags: python, command-line, pyqt, interaction

I have a text CLI based script written to test some equipment.  Some of the test requires entering back yes/no answers as well as reading the script's output.  I want to see if it's feasible to create a PyQT app. that can put a GUI front end on this type of interaction?  E.g. when the user clicks a button to run a script, the script is run sending it's output line at a time to a text window on the GUI, and any lines entered from the GUI are also sent down to the script.

TIA,
Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the criteria by which you'll be judging whether it's feasible or not?

It certainly is possible. The [QProcess](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QProcess.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QProcess.readAllStandardOutput) class provides everything that you would need for running and interacting with external processes inside a Qt application. At its core, it can do everything that `subprocess` can do (albeit, less conveniently). Here's a  contrived usage example:

```
button = QPushButton('start')
textedit = QTextEdit()
process = QProcess()

button.clicked.connect(on_clicked)

def on_clicked():
    process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(read_ready)
    process.start('/bin/sh',
       ('-c', "while /bin/true; do echo hello world ; sleep 1; done"))

def read_ready(self):
    chunk = process.readAllStandardOutput()
    textedit.append(str(chunk))
```

Since you're still at the planning stage, why not consider a tool such as [zenity](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/265/a-complete-zenity-dialog-examples-2/) for the GUI part? It could save you a lot of work. Getting a list of checkboxes and sending the output of a command to a textarea becomes a matter of:

```bsh
parameters=$(
zenity --list --text "Test parameters:" \
       --checklist --column "Check" --column "Parameter" \
       TRUE "One" TRUE "Two" TRUE "Three" FALSE "Four" \
       --separator=":");

# parameters -> One:Two:Three
./instrument-test.py $parameters | zenity --text-info
```

Best of luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In your Python example how would you read keystrokes from the textedit component and send them to STDIN of the process?

Comment: You could bind the [textChanged](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTextEdit.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTextEdit.textChanged) signal to a function that does `process.write(...)`. Another thing to consider - [konsolepart](http://api.kde.org/4.5-api/kdebase-apps-apidocs/konsole/html/classKonsole_1_1Part.html) from the KDE libs is a reusable terminal emulator component and can make this sort of interaction easier (and better looking) ([example](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdebindings/pykde4/repository/revisions/master/entry/examples/kpartsExamples/konsolepart.py)).